# Creating a scoring system from probabilities

Tags: probability, functions

Consider five events A, B, C, D, and E.  These events are not mutually exclusive.

I have a dataset that feeds into a model and then the model generates (outputs) the probabilities for the occurrence of events A, B, C, D, and E.

So, I want to create a score or metric that combines these five probabilities and gives me a number that will reflect the scenario for each instance of the datapoint.
Something like this:

\begin{equation}
Score=f(P(A), P(B),P(C),P(D),P(E))
\end{equation}

My ideal scenario will be when the probabilities of event A, B, and C are low and high for events D and E. I would like the score metric to reflect this idea.

How can I go about designing such a metric? Thanks.

Comment: "My ideal scenario will be when the probabilities of event A, B, and C are low and high for events D and E."  What does this mean?

Comment: @saulspatz I mean to say P(A) < 0.5 P(B) <0.5 P(C) <0.5 and P(D) >0.5 P(E) >0.5 is my ideal scenario. Since I am interested in creating a score using these values, I though adding some context will make more sense, as to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Why should the score be related to the probabilities at all?  Maybe some events are more favorable than others.  Assign a value to each event and let the score be the sum of the events which happen.  Often the low probability events are more favorable outcomes, but not always.  You need to think about what you want.  There will be a formula for it, but you can't just ask for a formula as an alternative to deciding what you want.

Comment: Not mutually exclusive would hinder the ideal scenario.